# When I'm starting the test I see 'data:,' in the chrome address bar and after few seconds the chrome window get closed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I'm starting the test I see 'data:,' in the chrome address bar and after few seconds the chrome window get closed instead of starting navigating to the url.

OS & Chrome info
Mac OS version: '10.11.1'
chrome version: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
ChromeDriver: 2.29.461585
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

```
Code:
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


 /**
 * Created by sangita on 03/06/17.
 */
 public class GmailSigninTest {
 @Test
  public void gmailloginShouldBeSuccessful() throws 
  InterruptedException {
 //1. Go to Gmail website
   System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/sangita/Downloads/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Thread.sleep(50000);
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");

    System.out.println("Hello Google...");
    driver.quit();



}

}
```

**Console error:**

```
objc[10065]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Starting ChromeDriver 
2.29.461585(0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b) on port 47628 Only local connections are allowed.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created 
exception
from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
(Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 
(0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.1 
x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3.61 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'Sangitas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.121', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.1', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
at GmailSigninTest.gmailloginShouldBeSuccessful(GmailSigninTest.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Is there any error thrown in the console?

Comment: Also, please show what code you're using.